# Moving files among azure blob without downloading

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

Currently, I have a blob container with about 5TB archive files. I need to move some of those files to another container. Is that a way to avoid download and upload files related? I do not need to access the data of those file. I do not want to get any bill about reading archive files either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you can use [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction). It usually used to transfer big data.

[Copy performance and scalability achievable using ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#copy-performance-and-scalability-achievable-using-adf):
[image]

You can learn from below tutorial:
[Copy and transform data in Azure Blob storage by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. For server-to-server data migrate, what the bandwidth for? It's the data level or meta-data level operating?

Comment: @scegg I think it's source data level. ADF offers a serverless architecture that allows parallelism at different levels, which allows developers to build pipelines to fully utilize your network bandwidth as well as storage IOPS and bandwidth to maximize data movement throughput for your environment. This means the throughput you can achieve can be estimated by measuring the minimum throughput offered by the source data store, the destination data store, and network bandwidth in between the source and destination.

Comment: Keep in mind, using ADF will incur a cost, although if this is a one time move it will probably be very small.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json) for that. It is a command line util that you can use to initiate server to server transfers:

> AzCopy uses server-to-server APIs, so data is copied directly between storage servers. These copy operations don't use the network bandwidth of your computer.

Comment: Thanks. It's the data level or meta-data level operating? Because it will need several hrs waiting time to access the data of archived files.